# Firebase Facebook login button does not change after user log out

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Facebook as a login in for my users to sign. When my users have to sign out I have a custom button made calling a sign out method that I made. When the user is signed out and go back to login screen the Facebook button still say logout when it should say login.

```
//my facebook button 
 lazy var facebookLogin:FBSDKLoginButton = {
        let v = FBSDKLoginButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

// my signout method
    let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
do {
  try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
} catch let signOutError as NSError {
  print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `logOut()` from `FBSDKLoginManager`

> Logs the user out
>
> This calls [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil] and [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil].

```
// my signout method
let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
do {
  try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
  FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
} catch let signOutError as NSError {
  print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
}
```

Don't forget to add `import FBSDKLoginKit` at the class where you use it

Comment: Great Answer on this one

Comment: Yeah, great that I could help you!